# how to get .opus audio file duration in swift

Tags: ios, swift, opus

I am using 'YbridPlayerSDK' library to play opus audio

```
   let myEndpoint = MediaEndpoint(mediaUri: audioURL.absoluteString)
    try AudioPlayer.open(for: myEndpoint, listener: nil) {
        (control) in /// called asychronously
        
        control.play()
        
    }
```

The above code play the audio but I am not able to find out its duration. how to get audio duration

Comment: Check the SDKs documentation.  
After i quick look you will recognize that they are providing a `AudioPlayerListener` protocol.